# Opening Same Screen in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I have a screen called Customer and has a parameter Id.

To open a screen through code I am using:

```
Application.ShowCustomer(customerId);
```

I am calling it in Customer Screen, but nothing happens. I can open a different screen, but I need to open same screen but with different entity.

I am not sure what is currently happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Customer Screen should have a parameter property you can modify. You could set this parameter value and refresh the screen. For example, I loaded my Customer screen with CustomerKey 1000 and added a button attached to a method called "differentCustomer":

```
    partial void differentCustomer_Execute()
    {
        // Instead of what you were doing:
        // Application.ShowCustomerDetail(5200);

        // Do this instead:
        this.CustomerCustomerKey = 5200;
        Refresh();
    }
```